# Use of terms from logic

Tags: logic

Users are building up some advances searches.
Like ((A or B) and (C or D)) and F

What should I call (
Is that a paren or parenthesis?
I don't have a space issue.

As a programmer and mathematician it is a paren.
What is it to to a non technical user?

Comment: I ran two searches over at english.stackexchange.com - one for [paren](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=paren), and one for [parenthesis](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=parenthesis). A few questions caught my eye as possibly being useful, though not directly answering your question.

Comment: The top result for each of the above searches where: "[Parentheses or parenthesis](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/130219/parentheses-or-parenthesis)", perhaps helping with singular and plural in your logic sentence. The other "[How to read “E = (mc)²” so as not to mistake for “E = mc²”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71052/how-to-read-e-mc%C2%B2-so-as-not-to-mistake-for-e-mc%C2%B2)" has some good answers that show a diverse number of ways to read parens... or parenthesis.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey I do want singular and would use the spoken term quantity mc squared.  Do you have an opinion on  paren or parenthesis or ??

Comment: @Blam Is it a *search engine* (e.g. web search) or a *query builder* (e.g. SQL)? In the first case, ordering (show items matching most terms first, fewer terms later), and simple force-inclusion (+) or exclusion (-) of terms normally work well (see how Google does their advanced search). In the second case, precision is a requirement (including incomplete matches is bad), so formal logic is necessary.

Comment: would they be advance users if they use advanced searches?

Comment: @Blam There are lots of names for (, only AB testing can tell you which name is best for your audience.

Comment: @ChairmanMeow Advanced is relative.  As stated they are non technical professionals that ARE building up advanced searches.  How does that affect what to call (?

Comment: @ChairmanMeow I am not going to do testing on this.  I just wanted an opinion on what to call it in the help / documentation.

Comment: @Blam it will be called differently in different help documentation, please think about that and how your question really depends on your audience and that's why you need to test it with your audience.  I've flagged this as off topic.

Answer (score 4):

**Locale and dialects may have more of an influence** than technical experience. When I studied Comp. Sci. here in Canada, we called "( )" brackets and "[ ]" square brackets.

I myself would call them **parentheses** (*parenthesis* singular) in any user documentation ([*paren* being an abbreviation of that term](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paren)), but I have no evidence to prove that this is any clearer or more used than any other term.

**More important to non-technical users will be clear, concrete examples** to help them understand and use the notation correctly. If you have clear examples, users will figure out any confusion they may have had with the terminology.

Comment: My question was not what to call them.  What to call )?  That is interesting you called it a bracket.  My users are non technical professionals in the the US.

Comment: In the U.S., they are definitely parentheses rather than brackets.  "Brackets" mean "square brackets" in U.S. parlance.  "Parens" is slang, and I would avoid it unless your documentation is very informal in tone.  Also non-technical people may not understand "parens".